# How to model guessing?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to model the knowledge of the student $i$, in a particular subject $S$. I give him a set of questions $Q$ from $S$ to test his knowledge. The level of his knowledge depends on the number of questions he gets it right. Suppose that questions were true or false and he does not know some of the question, there is 50% chance to get each one right by guessing. There is also a chance for him to make mistake (careless mistakes) even if he knew the subject. How do I model this? What will be the parameters of my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A question answered in much more generality by Mr. Tao:
https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/06/01/how-to-assign-partial-credit-on-an-exam-of-true-false-questions/

Enjoy!